# how to idangerous swiper direction rtl with jquery in wp

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress, swiper.js

how to idangerous swiper direction rtl with  jquery in wp?
I checked all related sources, but unfortunately no solution was provided
Please help if you can, the direction of rotation from left to right

My code is as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="swiper-container" dir="rtl">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/idangerous.swiper.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                slidesPerView: "auto",
                spaceBetween: 30,
            })
            jQuery('.swiper-button-prev').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault()
                mySwiper.swipePrev()
            })
            jQuery('.swiper-button-next').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault()
                mySwiper.swipeNext()
            })
        })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing the Swiper with reverseDirection set to true

https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-autoplay-reverseDirection

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    slidesPerView: "auto",
    spaceBetween: 30,
    reverseDirection: true,
})
```